# Is there a way to change file name without using rename system call?

Tags: linux, rename

In LINUX, I want to change file name not using system call `rename` and `renameat2`.
And shell command `mv` is also prohibited. (All shell command is prohibited.)

Hmm... I have no idea... lol...

Comment: use system calls write a gcc program and execute.

Comment: What's the point? What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to change file name, and execl and execv is also prohibited.

Comment: So, you want to change a file name you aren't allowed to change?

Comment: The standard unix command mv (which you want to emulate, I guess) works *within* file systems where it usually changes directory entries without copying contents around, but also *between* file systems, where it actually copies the data to the new destination and then deletes the source. So it does either what nos suggested below, or something equivalent to Kir's answer (but most likely with some low-level or OS specific approach, not stdlib buffered IO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use [link()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html) to create a new name for the file, and [unlink()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) to remove the existing name.

Be aware that using link(), or rename(), cannot move files from one file system("mount point") to another, in that case you would need to manually move the file as the answer by @KirChou says.

Comment: This will only work within the same file system, so it's a subset of mv. There, of course, it's massiveley preferred over any alternative.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `fopen("oldfile", "r")` to read data from old file.
2. Use `fopen("newfile", "w")` to write data to the new file.
3. Use `remove("oldfile")` to delete the old file.

Comment: Why so complicated? This is not Windows, things are simpler :)

Comment: @m0skit0: Sorry, I just provide one solution for his special question, if not suitable for stackoverflow, I will delete it later.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Question is tagged Linux, so I assume filesystem is Linux (ext-whatever), same as if question is tagged Windows, I will assume filesystem is Windows (NTFS).

Comment: @m0skit0 Not file system *types*, but systems proper, e.g. sda1 and sda2 (or to your USB medium). You can (usually, I guess -- who knows what modern distributed hybrids do) not link between them, because they do not share inodes.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry Peter, I don't know what you mean. I don't see how the hardware where the filesystem is stored is relevant.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, write a little test program and `link()` from / to /mount/usb or whatever. Then you'll understand. From http://linux.die.net/man/2/link: "Notes: Hard links, as created by link(), cannot span file systems."

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks, I didn't know that. He can use `symlink()` instead of that's a problem.

Comment: @m0skit0 `symlink()`seems not to go well with a delete of the source ;-)